# Iframe sends to the bottom of the page on firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<iframe  id="ifr" width="100%" height="1500" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="...url"></iframe>

<script>

let loaded = false;
window.scroll(function() {
    let height = window.scrollTop();
    if(height  > 500) {
        if(!loaded){
            let iframe = document.getElementById("ifr");
            iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
            loaded = true;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I am using this code, but I am not getting results, the iframe loads it when the page starts and automatically scrolls to the place where the iframe is placed (at the bottom).

When I open it in chrome I don't have any problem but in firefox I do.

Comment: Yes, just i forgot to update the code, i tried with lodead = true, the problem is still there

Comment: So you need an `iframe` that is loaded when the html page is scrolled and when it's visible after scroll. Right?

Comment: But i can't see `data-src` attribute only `src`..

Comment: @ChrisP You are right, I was adding the wrong code. Thank you!